# Recurrence with Two Variables

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve this recurrence relation
$$
f(a,b)=cf(\lceil\frac{a}{c}\rceil,b)+cf(a,b-1).
$$
The base cases are $f(a,2)=a$, $f(1, b)=1$, $c\geq{2}$, and $a, b, c\in{\mathbb{Z}^+}$. I tried to expand this relation, but I am confused about the termination conditions for different branches. Can anyone give me some clue about how to solve this recurrence relation?

Comment: What is the domain of the variables? IE must $a/c$ b an integer?

Comment: Letting $ c = 1$, we have $ f(a,b) = f(a,b) + f(a,b-1)$. Hence, $f(a,b-1) = 0 $ for all values, which is a contradiction. Can you recheck your recurrence relation?

Comment: @CalvinLin Updated. Sorry for the confusion.